# Want to know how to bypass strange result during runtime in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, runtime, runtime-error

The following code asks the user to choose a shape, enter the dimensions for said shape, and display its volume.

It is used mostly of variable declarations and function calls, as this is required.

When I run the code I get the following output :

[image]

I dont understand why - nan (ind) appears instead of the result.

here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double height, width, length, radius, base_area, result;

 //Function prototypes

int ReadInputShapeChoice();
void readshapedimension(int choice);
float CalculateBasicVolume(int choice);
void PrintResult(int choice);

double rectangular_solid(double length1, double width1, double height1);
double cylinder(double radius2, double height2);
double cone(double radius3, double height3);
double sphere(double radius4);
double square_based_pyramid(double height5, double base_area5);

//function definitions
double rectangular_solid(double length1, double width1, double height1)
{
    double value;
    value = (length1 * width1 * height1);
    return value;
}
double cylinder(double radius2, double height2)
{
    double value;
    value = (3.14159 * (radius2 * radius2) * height2);
    return value;
}
double cone(double radius3, double height3)
{
    double value;
    value = ((3.14159 * (radius3 * radius3) * height3) / 3);
    return value;
}
double sphere(double radius4)
{
    double value;
    value = ((3.14159 * (radius4 * radius4 * radius4))*(4 / 3));
    return value;
}
double square_based_pyramid(double height5, double base_area5)
{
    double value;
    value = ((height5 * base_area5) * (1 / 3));
    return value;

}


int ReadInputShapeChoice()
{   int choice;
    cout << "Choose what shape you want to calculate" << endl;
    cout << "1 = Rectangular solid" << endl;
    cout << "2 = Cylinder" << endl;
    cout << "3 = Cone" << endl;
    cout << "4 = Sphere" << endl;
    cout << "5 = Square based pyramid" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

void readshapedimension(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        int length, width, height;
        cout << "You have chosen rectuangular solid" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the values for length width and height" << endl;
        cin >> length >> width >> height;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        int radius, height;
        cout << "You have chosen cylinder" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the values for radius and height" << endl;
        cin >> radius >> height;
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        int radius, height;
        cout << "You have chosen cone" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the values for radius and height" << endl;
        cin >> radius >> height;
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        int radius;
        cout << "You have chosen sphere" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the radius" << endl;
        cin >> radius;
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        int height, base_area;
        cout << "You have chosen square based pyramid" << endl;
        cout << "Enter height and area of the base" << endl;
        cin >> height >> base_area;
        break;
    }
    }
}

float CalculateBasicVolume(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
        int result;
    case 1:
    {
        result = rectangular_solid(length, width, height);
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        result = cylinder(radius, height);
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        result = cone(radius, height);
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        result = sphere(radius);
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        result = square_based_pyramid(height, base_area);
        break;
    }
    return result;
    }
}
void PrintResult(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        cout << "The volume of the rectangular solid is " << result << endl;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        cout << "the volume of the cylinder is " << result << endl;
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        cout << "The volume of the cone is " << result << endl;
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        cout << "The volume of the sphere is " << result << endl;
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        cout << "the volume of the square based pyramid is " << result <<     endl;
        break;
    }

    }
    }



int main() {
    int choice;
    choice = ReadInputShapeChoice();
    readshapedimension(choice);
    result = CalculateBasicVolume(choice);
    PrintResult(choice);

        return 0;
}
```

PLease can someone help me find a way to modify this code, so that it outputs the correct results ? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the radius and height into *local* variables declared in your switch statement.  The *global* variables used in the calculation are never set, and have their default values of 0 in them.  Your calculation results in a 0.0 / 0.0, which results in your NaN (Not a Number).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, how would I go about switching them to global variables ? May sound silly but I thought I already did so at the start of the code .

Comment: @FlewittConnor You did, but you also have `int radius, height` under `case 3` which creates some local variables with the same name and a different type.  You're reading your inputs into the locals, not the globals.  To fix this just delete the variable declarations in the `case` statements in `readshapedimension`.